# Probability in two sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have two intervals **A=[0, a]** and **B=[0, b]** where a and b are positive integers. What is the probability of selecting an interval **[x,x+p]** (where *x* is any *REAL* number from *A* and *p* is any non negative integer) and an interval **[y,y+q]** (where *y* is any *REAL* number from *B* and *q* is any non negative integer) such that both the intervals contain something common, if selecting any x and y from A and B respectively are equally preferred?

Comment: $x+p$ (respectively, $y+q$) is not an interval; it's a value.  Do you mean $[x, x+p]$ (respectively, $[y, y+q]$)?

Comment: yes sorry for that... and the interval is closed.
edited it

Comment: You should specify the distribution for selecting **x** and **y**. I'll assume, though, that's a Uniform distribution.

Comment: yes that is a uniform distribution.. edited it

Answer (score 0):

Let $X,Y$ be r.v. for selecting $x,y$. $X\sim U(0,a), Y\sim U(0,b)$. I'll use $<$ rather than $\leq $ because $P(X=z)=0\ \ \forall z $

$$P(Y< X< Y+q\ \cup X< Y< X+p)=\\
P(Y< X< Y+q )+P( X< Y< X+p)-0$$

I'll find the first term of the sum. The other would be the same changing $a$, $b$ and $q$ for $b$, $a$ and $p$ respectively.

$$P(Y< X< Y+q)=P(Y<X \cap X<Y+q)=\\
P(X>Y)P(X<Y+q\mid X>Y)=\\
\int_0^bP(X>x)\frac{dx}{b}\int_0^bP(X>x+q\mid X>x)\frac{dx}{b}=\\
\int_0^b\frac{a-x}{a}\frac{dx}{b}\int_0^b\frac{q}{a-x}\frac{dx}{b}=\\
\left.\frac{2ax-x^2}{2ab}\right| _0^b \left. \frac{q\log(b(a-x))}{b}\right| _0^b=\\
\frac{2a-b}{2a}\frac{q\log(\frac{a}{a-b})}{b}$$

And from there you should be able to solve it. You'll want to find:

$$\frac{(2a-b)q\log(\frac{a}{a-b})}{2ab}+\frac{(2b-a)p\log(\frac{b}{b-a})}{2ab}
$$

Even though, from that equation, if $p>b$ change $p$ for $b$. Likewise, if $q>a$, change $q$ for $a$.